# Getting the GUID for any given path to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, api, guid

I'm trying to get the GUID of a given sharepoint URL. I don't mind using the API or the webservices or Sharepoint's database.

if i were to write a function, it's signature would be:
//get a GUID from path.
string GetGuidFromPath(string path){}

I had a lead: SPContentMapProvider but it doesn't seem to get the right info.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depends - what's the context of the current request? Is your code running in the context of a SharePoint request? If so you can just use `SPContext.Current.Web.ID`

Otherwise, is your code at least running on one of the SharePoint servers? If so you'll need to use:

```
// Given the URL http://mysharepointsite.com/sites/somesite/somesubsite

using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysharepointsite.com/sites/somesite"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("somesubsite"))
    {
        Guid webId = web.ID;
    }

    // Or
    Guid rootWebId = site.RootWeb.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer,

Let's say my URL is this:

http://argentina:94/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx
or:
http://argentina:94/Lists/Tasks/My%20View.aspx
which is the same page (with a different view)
how would I use the above code?

Thank you!!!